# Use @Autowired in Spring MVC and JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I have spring mvc project and i don't use `@Autowired` because my object always is `null`. How me load `JavaConfig` for using `@Autowired`, i do not use any *.xml file.

This is my **controller** with `@Autowired` field for service.

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceWeb serviceWeb;

    public void setServiceWeb(ServiceWeb serviceWeb) {
        this.serviceWeb = serviceWeb;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is my **AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer**

```
public class ServletInit extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**SpringRootConfig & SpringWebConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"web.controller"})
public class SpringRootConfig {
}

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "web.controller"})
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
                = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Class for `@Autowiring`

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationBean {
    @Bean
    public ServiceWeb serviceWeb(){
        return new ServiceWebImpl();
    }
}
```

Register context for spring, but where need write `Init.class` for loading this config ?

```
public class Init implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ConfigurationBean.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this...

```
@Service
public class ServiceWebImpl implements ServiceWeb {

}
```

ServiceWeb bean is created inside ConfigurationBean class and its not visible at spring context level for autowiring.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Agree with your point @Fabio but i suggested my answer based on my observation above.